# Deleting events - recycle bin issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, delete, events, bin

I've noticed that when deleting events, as a user would go on the FE and delete their own event, it doesn't send the event to the Recycle bin and the event disappears.
Only when deleting the events from the "Events" lists accessible through Site contents, the event goes to the recycle bin as it should.

Any suggestions or ideas what is the reason for this?

Comment: what does "go on the FE" mean?

Comment: On the Front end, meaning as a simple user who has access to create/edit/delete his own events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, you mean to delete the event through **Event web part**, the event will not appear in the Recycle bin. But enter the **Events list** through Site contents to delete the event, the event will appear in the Recycle bin.

This is a normal phenomenon, because the event is deleted through **Event web part**. The type of this event is an "**Event**", and the Recycle bin does not support this type.

But if the event is deleted through the **Events list**, the type of this event will be defined as **ListItem**, so it will appear in the Recycle bin.

**Here is my test:**

This is my Events list named "Cal1"

[image]

Delete "Event111"

[image]

Deleted event "Event111" will appear in the Recycle bin

[image]

Go to the page with Event web part

[image]

Delete "Event333"

[image]

Deleted event "Event333" will not appear in the Recycle bin

[image]

Please run the following powershell script, you can see the type of "Event111" is ListItem and there is no "Event333"

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get Recycle bin Items
Get-PnPRecycleBinItem | Select Title, ItemType, Size, ItemState, DirName, DeletedByName, DeletedDate | Format-table -AutoSize
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the exact case. 
So this means that there is no way for a deleted event to go to the recycle bin without it being deleted as a Listitem?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct